# What is the reason why it's normal to write Pluperfect in a 'nachdem' sentence, but it's incorrect in a 'bevor' sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure, pluperfect

The standard Pluperfect verb form in a 'nachdem' sentence is the following:

> Nachdem ich Fußball gespielt hatte, duschte ich zu Hause.

The example sentence in a 'bevor' sentence is:

> Bevor ich zu Hause duschte, spielte ich Fußball.

**My question is, what is the reason why I cannot write the standard Pluperfect verb form in a 'bevor' sentence-structure?**

> Bevor ich zu Hause duschte, hatte ich Fußball gespielt.

Comment: And who says you can't use the third version?

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption, that you "cannot write" the version using pluperfect is wrong.

Both versions are totally valid and can be found in German language.

Usually we just don't use the "complicated" form with pluperfect in cases where the timing is totally clear without it: In your example *of course* you had finished playing soccer, *before* you took a shower -> no need to use pluperfect to make that clear.